# Error message on installation of 14.04

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

Every time I to install I keep getting this error message.

[http://imgur.com/UzsdKAj](https://imgur.com/UzsdKAj)

I successfully burnt the disc image and then I changed the boot settings to boot from the CD. It brings me to a screen where I am then able to select my language. After I select "install Ubuntu" or "try Ubuntu without installation" I get the same error message every time.

I have never used Linux before so I don't know if this is a common error or not. I did some research and couldn't find a solution but apparently nouveau is the graphics driver? I don't know how to fix it but here is my current PC build if it helps any.

CPU: Intel i5-4690K
Graphics card: nvidia gtx 980
Motherboard: MSI Z97-GD65 Gaming ATX LGA1150 Motherboard
Ram: 16 GB
Storage: Crucial MX100 512GB SSD (primary) and a Western digital 4TB HDD

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You need to boot with `nomodeset` parameter. Your video card is not supported by the default driver.

Comment: It did progress an extra screen to where it said Ubuntu and then had blinking dots along the bottom. After about 5 or so minutes it froze and didn't do anything for about 15 minutes. I tried to restart the computer but now even when I select the nomodeset parameter it no longer brings up the second screen but instead gives the same message.